# django ORM: Filter results differ between shell and application

Tags: django, filter, orm

I've got a headache-causing issue regarding the filter-function within django ORM:

The filter function returns different values if executed in the manage.py shell compared to the actual application I'm building.

**What I try to achieve:** Querying all entries in my sqlite database by using the ORM's filter-function targeting a foreign-key relationship.

a) Executed in the shell it returns the actual expected results.

b) Executed the same way from within the application it returns a completely different (and bigger) subset of results.

**Relevant Models:**

```
class ZeitbuchungHead(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datum = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(ZeitbuchungStatus, related_name='zeitstatus', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ZeitbuchungDetail(models.Model):

    zeitbuchung_head = models.ForeignKey(ZeitbuchungHead, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    zeit_von = models.TimeField()
    zeit_bis = models.TimeField()
    zeitbuchungsart = models.ForeignKey(ZeitbuchungArten, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Database:**

[ZeitbuchungHead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByMMv.png)

[ZeitbuchungDetail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtmWY.png)

**Shell-Query:**

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: from erfassung_app import models

In [3]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [4]: u = User.objects.get(username='TestUser1')

In [5]: date = datetime.date.today()

In [6]: head = models.ZeitbuchungHead.objects.get(user=u, datum=date)
In [8]: details = models.ZeitbuchungDetail.objects.filter(zeitbuchung_head = head)

In [9]: print(details)
<QuerySet [<ZeitbuchungDetail: TestUser1 2018-04-09 00:00:00 08:00:00 09:00:00 Arbeitszeit>, <ZeitbuchungDetail: TestUser1 2018-04-09 00:00:00 08:00:00 09:00:00 Arbeitszeit>, <ZeitbuchungDetail: TestUser1 2018-04-09 00:00:00 08:00:00 09:00:00 Arbeitszeit>, <ZeitbuchungDetail: TestUser1 2018-04-09 00:00:00 08:00:00 09:00:00 Arbeitszeit>, <ZeitbuchungDetail: TestUser1 2018-04-09 00:00:00 08:00:00 09:00:00 Arbeitszeit>, <ZeitbuchungDetail: TestUser1 2018-04-09 00:00:00 08:00:00 09:00:00 Arbeitszeit>, <ZeitbuchungDetail: TestUser1 2018-04-09 00:00:00 08:00:00 09:00:00 Arbeitszeit>]>

In [10]: details_number = models.ZeitbuchungDetail.objects.filter(zeitbuchung_head = head).count()

In [11]: print(details_number)
7
```

*Result:*

- See line 09 for filter-query => correct result = 7 Entries.
- See line 11 for number of entries.

**Application-Query:**

```
@staticmethod
    def application_method():
        date = datetime.date.today()
        u = User.objects.get(username='TestUser1')
        head = m.ZeitbuchungHead.objects.get(user=u, datum=date)
        all_details_for_head = m.ZeitbuchungDetail.objects.filter(zeitbuchung_head = head)
```

*Result:*

- Query-Result

[Application-Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY1mF.png)

- Actual number of items: 18

**My Questions:**

1) What could be the reason for the difference in results?

2) How can I tackle this issue properly? I debugged it in many ways but do not get a grasp on the issue.

**Note**: I tried it with different filter-queries and ran into identical problems.

Comment: print the date value in both and see if it is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was somehow hard to spot. The debugger I was using does not function properly in terms of ORM-queries (which was previously working fine). I am using VS code 1.22.1 + Django 2.0. Couldn't resolve the problem with my debugger, but the code is actually working totally fine when run with manage.py's runserver cmd.

It seems to be related with the following issue:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/204